# The inverse of the Gamma function at $-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, gamma-function

Let $\Gamma$ be the analytic continuation of the Gamma function $$\Gamma:z\mapsto \int_0^{+\infty} x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx$$ on the complex plane except non-positive integers.

We know that $\Gamma$ has no zeros but simple poles on $\{0,-1,-2,-3,\ldots\}$.
So if we define $G:z\mapsto \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(z)}$, this is an entire function with only simple zeros at $\{0,-1,-2,-3,\ldots\}$.

My questions are the followings:

> What is the behavior between two zeros of $G$ ? What is the growth of $G$ in $[-(n+1),-n]$? 
>   Do we know if, for
>   example, $\displaystyle \dfrac{e^{- t^2}}{\Gamma(t)} \underset{t\to -\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$ ?

Comment: From the reflection formula 
$-z\Gamma(z)\Gamma(-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$
you get
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}= -\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z\pi\Gamma(-z)}$$
Now plugin your favorite formula for $z$ with $\Re z > 0$.

Comment: Great, thank you. So the limit I was asking is true with Stirling's formula.